# Accounting Balances. Hierarchial Balances and Rollup

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Accounts (Master List of Accounts with link to their parent (same table) )
(Accounts table is maintained using nested_set plugin, so the left, right, depth are available in the table and are maintained while adding/editing accounts)

```
| id | name           | parent_id |
|----|----------------|-----------|
| 1  | Assets         | null      |
| 2  | Current Assets | 1         |
| 3  | Fixed Assets   | 1         |
| 4  | Bank           | 2         |
| 5  | Bank One       | 4         |
| 6  | Bank Two       | 4         |
| 7  | Revenue        | null      |
| 8  | Sales          | 7         |
| 9  | Expenses       | null      |
| 10 | Rent           | 9         |
```

Entries  (where the date and description of each transaction stored)

```
| entry_id | date       | description        |
|----------|------------|--------------------|
| 1        | Mar 3 2020 | Cash Sales         |
| 2        | Mar 3 2020 | Cash Paid For Rent |
| 3        | Apr 1 2020 | Owner Withdrawal   |
```

Amounts (where the double entry transactions are stored)

```
| entry_id | account_id | type   | amount |
|----------|------------|--------|--------|
| 1        | 5          | debit  | 10000  |
| 1        | 8          | credit | 10000  |
| 2        | 10         | debit  | 1000   |
| 2        | 5          | credit | 1000   |
|          |            |        |        |
```

Given the above structure, here is my requirements

1. Arrange the accounts in Tree(hierarchical) structure and calculate the individual account balances (balances can be debit_balance or credit_balance)
2. Hierarchical account balances, rolling up child balances to the parent accounts

PS:
I do have the solution for the req 1 above using a combination of
WITH RECURSIVE sql function on the accounts table and arranging the rows hierarchially and then joining the result set with amounts table that is summed up on amount column (after grouping on type) for each accounts.
I am keen to see how the folks over here will solve this. (lemme know  if you would like to see what I got so far though)

here is the query that gets me the first result set. (i've omitted the details like normal_credit_blance flag etc for brevity in the original question)

```
        select id, parent_id, name, newdepth as depth, debit_amount, credit_amount, type,
        CASE WHEN normal_credit_balance = true THEN  credit_amount - debit_amount END as credit_balance,
            CASE WHEN normal_credit_balance = false THEN  debit_amount - credit_amount END as debit_balance

        from
        (
        WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
        SELECT id, parent_id, display_name, lft, rgt, type, normal_credit_balance, 0 as newdepth
        FROM accounts
        WHERE parent_id is null 
        UNION
        SELECT op.id, op.parent_id, op.display_name, op.lft, op.rgt, op.type, op.normal_credit_balance, newdepth + 1
        FROM accounts op
        JOIN children c ON op.parent_id = c.id
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM children 
        ) accounts_tbl 
        left join 

        ( SELECT  account_id, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN am.type =  'debit' THEN COALESCE( AMOUNT , 0.0 ) ELSE 0.0 END ) AS debit_amount ,
          SUM( CASE WHEN am.type =  'credit' THEN   COALESCE( AMOUNT , 0.0 ) ELSE 0.0 END ) AS credit_amount
          FROM amounts am
        join accounts ac on ac.id = am.account_id
          group by account_id, ac.name, ac.type ) 
          
        as  amount_tbl  

        on accounts_tbl.id = amount_tbl.account_id order by lft
```

sample result based on the amounts table entries,  the rollup should look like this:

```
| id | name           | balance   |  
|----|----------------|-----------|            
| 1  | Assets         | 9000      |            
| 2  | Current Assets | 9000      |            
| 3  | Fixed Assets   | 0         |            
| 4  | Bank           | 9000      |            
| 5  | Bank One       | 9000      |            
| 6  | Bank Two       | 0         |            
| 7  | Revenue        | 10000     |
| 8  | Sales          | 10000     |
| 9  | Expenses       | 1000      |
| 10 | Rent           | 1000      |
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text. I would also be useful to show us your current query, and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: @GMB, edited the question to include your suggestions. the current query is fine for getting the group wise totals on the account hierarchy, but it doesn't do the account balance  roll up to the parents which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks. But you are yet to show the result that you expect for your sample data.

Comment: @GMB, pls see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by computing the "direct" balance of each account, with a `left join` and aggregation. Then goes the recursive query: you just need to traverse the tree from the leafs to the root, conslidating the balance as you go. The final step is aggregation.

```
with recursive
    data (id, name, parent_id, balance) as (
        select 
            ac.*, 
            coalesce(sum(case am.type when 'debit' then - amount when 'credit' then amount end), 0) balance
        from accounts ac
        left join amounts am on am.account_id = ac.id
        group by ac.id
    ),
    cte (id, name, parent_id, balance) as (
        select d.* from data d
        union all
        select d.id, d.name, d.parent_id, d.balance + c.balance
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.id = c.parent_id
    )
select id, name, sum(balance) from cte group by id, name
```

I don't get how all the accounts in your resultset end up with a positive balance, while some have more debits than credit (and vice-versa). The query treats debits as negative amounts and credits as positive.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=65bdb3c298dabc7822bd1e991bc2a120)**:

```
id | name           |   sum
-: | :------------- | ----:
 1 | Assets         | -9000
 2 | Current Assets | -9000
 3 | Fixed Assets   |     0
 4 | Bank           | -9000
 5 | Bank One       | -9000
 6 | Bank Two       |     0
 7 | Revenue        | 10000
 8 | Sales          | 10000
 9 | Expenses       | -1000
10 | Rent           | -1000
```

Comment: Thank You, looks perfect on the fiddle. Will need to apply this on my code (there are few more conditions etc that needs to be added etc). I will check in couple of hours and will accept the answer. Thanks again for all the efforts!

Comment: Regarding credit/debit being possitive, we could have modelled the amount column to accept opposite transaction with -ve values for debit and credit accounts, we chose to go with having an account type instead and leaving the value as is. and then doing a sum diff on debit and credit to get the actual balance. We might make the amount column to go with -ve and +ve values, but do not want to change it to that atm. and also until we investigate that case thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a closure table instead of nested sets (like I do in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802) then you could use simple JOINs like

```sql
SELECT 
  accounts.id, 
  accounts.title, 
  SUM(COALESCE(debits.amount,0)) AS debit, 
  SUM(COALESCE(credit.amount,0)) AS credit
FROM account_tree
LEFT JOIN accounts ON ancestor_id = accounts.id
LEFT JOIN balances AS debits ON account_id = child_id AND type = 'debit'
LEFT JOIN balances AS credits ON account_id = child_id AND type = 'credit'
GROUP BY accounts.id,accounts.title
```

As a side note I would recommend you to keep debits and credits on the same row - as 2 columns in table BALANCES.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to have a solution that doesn't involve a trigger if possible. (Triggers are often overlooked in the code unfortunately  and make code reasoning harder)

Comment: Are you sure that your plugin does not use any trigger ? It is even harder to reason if you can not see the source code of the trigger ...